# Why the process still can be listed after killing them?

Tags: debian, process, vlc

List all process running vlc:

```
debian@debian:~$ ps aux |grep vl[c]
debian     14482  0.1  2.2 2882968 136428 ?      Sl   10:19   0:02 vlc -I telnet --telnet-host 192.168.31.167 --telnet-port 4212 --telnet-password admin
debian     15174  0.2  2.4 2881576 145368 ?      Ssl  10:32   0:03 vlc -d -I telnet --telnet-host 192.168.31.167 --telnet-port 4212 --telnet-password admin
debian     15641  0.3  2.4 2896668 146380 ?      SLsl 10:42   0:01 vlc -d -I telnet --telnet-host 192.168.31.167 --telnet-port 4212 --telnet-password admin
```

Kill them all:

```
debian@debian:~$ sudo kill 14482
debian@debian:~$ sudo kill 15174
debian@debian:~$ sudo kill 15641
```

List again:

```
debian@debian:~$ ps aux |grep vl[c]
debian     14482  0.1  2.2 2882968 136428 ?      Sl   10:19   0:02 vlc -I telnet --telnet-host 192.168.31.167 --telnet-port 4212 --telnet-password admin
debian     15174  0.2  2.4 2881576 145368 ?      Ssl  10:32   0:03 vlc -d -I telnet --telnet-host 192.168.31.167 --telnet-port 4212 --telnet-password admin
debian     15641  0.3  2.4 2896668 146380 ?      SLsl 10:42   0:01 vlc -d -I telnet --telnet-host 192.168.31.167 --telnet-port 4212 --telnet-password admin
```

Why the process still can be listed after killing them?

Comment: because `kill` doesn't *guarantee* the process will be killed ... `kill -9` *almost* guarantees it, but use only as a last resort

Comment: Even after a process terminates, its zombie is still present until its parent `wait()`s for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out `man kill`:

```
KILL(1)                         User Commands                        KILL(1)

NAME
       kill - send a signal to a process

SYNOPSIS
       kill [options] <pid> [...]

DESCRIPTION
       The  default signal for kill is TERM.  Use -l or -L to list available
       signals.  Particularly useful signals include HUP, INT,  KILL,  STOP,
       CONT,  and  0.  Alternate signals may be specified in three ways: -9,
       -SIGKILL or -KILL.  Negative PID values may be used to  choose  whole
       process  groups;  see the PGID column in ps command output.  A PID of
       -1 is special; it indicates all processes except the kill process it‐
       self and init.
```

At the very top is says: "send a signal to a process".  This does not mean the process will be killed, only that it will be sent a signal.

The default signal is `SIGTERM`.  According to `man signal.7`, `SIGTERM` is catchable.  This means, the program receives a request to stop, then the program has the opportunity to do something about it.  If it's a database, maybe it will save before stopping.

If the program doesn't handle `SIGTERM`, or chooses to do something other than stop, you'll get the behaviour you see.

There are other signals you could try to send.  `SIGINT` (2) is the same thing you send when using CTRL+C in the terminal.  A common one, and probably the one you want is `SIGKILL` (9).  `SIGKILL` is one of the few signals that will not be propagated to the process.  Instead it is a signal to the kernel, asking it to kill the process.  In this case, it doesn't matter if the process is coded to handle `SIGTERM`, it will be stopped by the kernel without being notified.  The disadvantage is if it needs to save its work, or notify peers that it is shutting down, it will not have the opportunity. Usage is like this:

```
$ sudo kill -9 14482
or
$ sudo kill -KILL 94471
```

`man signal.7` has more details. If your machine isn't the same as mine, then use the man page on your machine for reference.

```
   Standard signals
       Linux supports the standard signals listed below.  The second  column
       of  the table indicates which standard (if any) specified the signal:
       "P1990" indicates that  the  signal  is  described  in  the  original
       POSIX.1-1990 standard; "P2001" indicates that the signal was added in
       SUSv2 and POSIX.1-2001.

       Signal      Standard   Action   Comment
       ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
─
       SIGABRT      P1990      Core    Abort signal from abort(3)
       SIGALRM      P1990      Term    Timer signal from alarm(2)
       SIGBUS       P2001      Core    Bus error (bad memory access)
       SIGCHLD      P1990      Ign     Child stopped or terminated
       SIGCLD         -        Ign     A synonym for SIGCHLD
       SIGCONT      P1990      Cont    Continue if stopped
       SIGEMT         -        Term    Emulator trap
       SIGFPE       P1990      Core    Floating-point exception
       SIGHUP       P1990      Term    Hangup detected on controlling terminal
                                       or death of controlling process
       SIGILL       P1990      Core    Illegal Instruction
       SIGINFO        -                A synonym for SIGPWR
       SIGINT       P1990      Term    Interrupt from keyboard
       SIGIO          -        Term    I/O now possible (4.2BSD)
       SIGIOT         -        Core    IOT trap. A synonym for SIGABRT
       SIGKILL      P1990      Term    Kill signal
       SIGLOST        -        Term    File lock lost (unused)
       SIGPIPE      P1990      Term    Broken pipe: write to pipe with no

                                       readers; see pipe(7)
       SIGPOLL      P2001      Term    Pollable event (Sys V);
                                       synonym for SIGIO
       SIGPROF      P2001      Term    Profiling timer expired
       SIGPWR         -        Term    Power failure (System V)
       SIGQUIT      P1990      Core    Quit from keyboard
       SIGSEGV      P1990      Core    Invalid memory reference
       SIGSTKFLT      -        Term    Stack fault on coprocessor (unused)
       SIGSTOP      P1990      Stop    Stop process
       SIGTSTP      P1990      Stop    Stop typed at terminal
       SIGSYS       P2001      Core    Bad system call (SVr4);
                                       see also seccomp(2)
       SIGTERM      P1990      Term    Termination signal
       SIGTRAP      P2001      Core    Trace/breakpoint trap
       SIGTTIN      P1990      Stop    Terminal input for background process
       SIGTTOU      P1990      Stop    Terminal output for background process
       SIGUNUSED      -        Core    Synonymous with SIGSYS
       SIGURG       P2001      Ign     Urgent condition on socket (4.2BSD)
       SIGUSR1      P1990      Term    User-defined signal 1
       SIGUSR2      P1990      Term    User-defined signal 2
       SIGVTALRM    P2001      Term    Virtual alarm clock (4.2BSD)
       SIGXCPU      P2001      Core    CPU time limit exceeded (4.2BSD);
                                       see setrlimit(2)
       SIGXFSZ      P2001      Core    File size limit exceeded (4.2BSD);
                                       see setrlimit(2)
       SIGWINCH       -        Ign     Window resize signal (4.3BSD, Sun)

       The signals SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be  caught,  blocked,  or  ig‐
       nored.
```